# Get a list of Fonts in c++ in linux

Tags: c++, linux, gtk

I am developing a plugin for a word processor using c++ in Linux. I need to get all the installed fonts to a list box.
I tried the Font Dialog which provided by GTK+. But it is giving the many features which I do not need.I could not found any other good solution for this.
I am using gtk and goffice libraries. It is better if I can do it without adding any external libraries.
Can someone please help to do this.

Comment: If you don't feel like learning about the fontconfig API, you could simply run `popen("fc-list", "r")` and parse its output. This is simple to implement and will work on most systems.

Comment: It is better if I can do it without adding new API

Comment: You don't need to "add" new API, just use the API provided by fontconfig. But as I said, you can also `popen("fc-list", "r")` and read from the pipe.